# What pronoun to use: whoever or whomever?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

I'm confused. What pronoun will be correct to use in this sentence?
"I can be whomever/whoever I want."

Comment: If you remember that _nobody says 'whomever'_ you won't go far wrong.

Comment: The following site gives a detailed explanation of the use of the two words. But, as Michael says, "whomever" now really belongs in the etymological museum.  https://www.grammarly.com/blog/2-effective-ways-to-deal-with-whoeverwhomever-confusion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly, you would use whoever, the 'nominative form'. Use who whenever he, she, they, I, or we is used the following clause.

I can be whoever I want [to be].

Also, strictly, you would use whomever, the 'objective form' whenever him, her, them, me, or us could be substituted as the object of the verb or as the object of a preposition in a following clause.

I will hire whomever I can find. (I can find her.)

This strict distinction is almost never followed in ordinary speech, and even fairly formal writing. The 'whom' form is considered too formal or stilted by many people nowadays, especially in spoken English.